# Why we have to bind a method in Class Component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading the documentation and practicing some things in the React documentation until I finally entered the event handling section. but I don't understand why when using method in class component we have to bind the function, can anyone explain it? for examples :

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: to bind `this` to `this.handleClick` - since without it, `this` in `handleClick` will be the element that the `click` happened on - i.e. it'd be the `<button` - the comment `// This binding is necessary to make \`this\` work in the callback` explains it nicely

Answer (score 2):

The point is to keep correct value of `this` reference. Check this example:

```js
class Example {
  private prop = 1;

  echoProp() {
    console.log(this?.prop);
  }
}

const example = new Example();
example.echoProp();
const echoPropRef = example.echoProp;
echoPropRef();
```

In the console you will see `1` and then `undefined`. This is because:

1. `Example:echoProp`'s `this` reference is instance of `Example` class, so it see also `prop` property.
2. if you pass `Example:echoProp`'s reference to another variable (`const echoPropRef = example.echoProp` - there is no `()`), then `this` reference is changed into `undefined`.

`bind` function "freezes" `this` reference, so it will be always the same; in you example it will be reference to `Toggle` class.

The `bind` is necessary if you use code like

```js
<button onClick={this.handleClick}>
```

Answer (score 0):

When `handleClick` is triggered by the button, `this` value inside `handleClick` will be the click event (this is js behaviour for event listener), but the click event does not have a `setState` method, which belongs to the component itself. So you want to bind the method to the component, so that `this` value inside `handleClick` will be the `Toggle` component which has the `setState` method

Answer (score 0):

The `this` is problem is a general problem in JS (not limited to React).

Normally inside a method, `this` refers to the current object instance.

Inside an event listener (even if its a method), `this` refers to the event target.

The `this` in `this.setState` must refer to the Component instance.

So to change the value of `this`, *binding* is done in the constructor.

Another solution would be

```
onClick={(evt)=>{handleClick(evt)}}
```

In this case `handleClick` ceases being an event listener and the actual event listener would be the anonymous function inside `onClick`.

The simplest alternative is :

```
handleClick=(evt)=>{
    this.setState(...)
}
```

Arrow functions do not have their *own* `this` & hence acquire the current object (component) instance as `this`.